# Exception has occurred. Where is the actual error for this problem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, setstate

when I run the apps, it still fine when i move to screen B from screen A. after i move to screen C and go back to screen A, this error happen:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (setState() called after dispose(): _AdminViewListState#e9f3a(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().)
```

can somebody help me to figure out what is the problem?

The error pointed at this code:

```
setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
```

and this is the whole coding:

```
class AdminViewList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AdminViewListState createState() => _AdminViewListState();
}

class _AdminViewListState extends State<AdminViewList> {
  var loading = false;

  final list = new List<AttractionModel>();
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refresh = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
  Future<void> _viewData() async{
    list.clear();
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(BaseUrl.viewAttraction);
    if (response.contentLength == 2) {
      
    } else {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      data.forEach((api){
        final ab = new AttractionModel(
          api['id'], 
          api['attractionName'], 
          api['description'], 
          api['price'], 
          api['createdData'], 
          api['idUsers'], 
          api['name'],
          );
          list.add(ab);
      });
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

in my debug console :

```
I/BufferQueueProducer(25860): [SurfaceTexture-0-25860-1](this:0x7b4bcac000,id:1,api:1,p:386,c:-1) disconnect(P): api 1
```

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: i have edited my question. please help me..

Comment: Can't understand your problem. Are you facing problems in navigating to different screens(as mentioned in the first line) or is it something else?

Comment: yes. something like that. i also got error stated in my debug console. i've edited in my question.

Comment: Ok, but i can't see any navigation problem in the code that you've provided. Please explain your problem clearly, so that i can help you.

Comment: i don't know how to explain it. i don't know whether that code is related to my problem or not because when i run the apps, that error (at first line) appeared as i mentioned. ok my problem now is, in my apps, i got 4 pages. Home, Add Item, Location, and Profile. i;ve got no problem when i navigate from Home to Add Item, Location, and Profile. And i got no problem to navigate from Add Item and Location too. But, i got problem when i navigate from Profile direct to Home. i'm sorry for my bad explanation. i'm not so good in english.

Comment: Hi Hardik Kumar! thank you for your time to help but i already got the solutionn hehehe. Thank you againn. i appreciate it!

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You have shown us a private method, and we don't even know how or when it's called.

Comment: i've already posted in my answer :) Hope its help.

Answer (score 0):

It's run well after I add this code

```
if (!mounted) return;
```

before

```
setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
```